# Excel: An array in an array?

Tags: excel-formula

So, I would like to return the contents of all rows where the value in column A is, let's say, 1.

My thought process is that I could use:

```
=INDEX(row_range,MATCH(1,A:A,0),0))
```

But Match will only return one value here, i.e. the number of the first row which contains a `1` in column `A`.

Is there a way of creating an array with the Match formula (thus returning the multiple row numbers, all of which contain '1' in column A) and then place that in the Index array so that it then runs through each of the Match-array values and creates a big long list of values in one array which I can then list out on a separate sheet?
Hope this makes sense...

Here is a demonstration of what I'm hoping for, if that helps! The idea would be that the array as shown would be created, which could then be extended down the column as per the part underneath.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCusM.png

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. Also, if it were, I would still hesitate to implement it as it would be an ugly and hard to debug monster. This feels like it would be more appropriate for VBA.

Comment: Yes it is possible with array formula, but as @JNevill this would be better accomplished with vba.

Comment: with your photo, I rescind my comment and say, use vba.

Comment: Ah crap... now I need to learn a whole new programming language!! :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the file you showed in your example (as "Sheet1") and put these formulas into indicated cells in Sheet2:
Into cell A2 put

```
=AGGREGATE(15;6;ROW(Sheet1!A:A)/((Sheet1!A:A=1)*1);ROW(A1))
```

this will give you all the rownumbers where value in A column of sheet1 equals 1.
Into cell B2 put

```
=COUNTA(INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&A2&":"&A2))-1
```

this will give you how many cells are filled in that row.
Into cell C2 put

```
=TEXTJOIN(",";TRUE;OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1;A2-1;1;1;B2))
```

This will give you all the cells with data from that row concatenated. If you dont have this formula (first time in 2016 I believe) you can use OFFSET function to list the values in separate columns and then CONCATENATE them.

Copy these three down as many times as you want and into cell C1 put

```
=TEXTJOIN(",";TRUE;OFFSET(C2;0;0;COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A;1);1))
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, that is brilliant - works perfectly! Thanks ever so much :-) Used a left+right formula to break the cell up into an individual running-column so now have a full list working!

Comment: Glad I could help. Please, mark the question as answered (accept the answer) - helps people sort what is already solved and what is not. Thanks